# Ошибка с рамками ImageAI

Tags: python

Использую ImageAi, Python 3.7, рамки около определенных объектов есть, а у других нет, как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: почему imageAI не отмечает все обьекты